# Выборка по массиву SQL

Tags: sql

Как сделать выборку по массиву объектов со свойствами a1 и a2? Выбрать все элементы где a1 элемента равно a1 какого-нибудь элемента из массива и a2 равно a2 того же элемента из массива.

Comment: напишите подробнее, так непонятно

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table t1
where exists(
select 1 from table t2 
where t1.a1=t2.a1 and t1.a2=t2.a2 and t1.id <> t2.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. у вас есть таблица в которой есть колонки a1 и a2 и вам надо выбрать строки у которых a1 и a2 одинаковые (у строк а не строки)?

Наверное как то так:

```
select * 
from table 
where (a1||a2) in 
   (
    select a1a2 from 
     (select count(*) as cnt,
             (a1||a2) as a1a2 
      from table 
      group by a1,a2) 
    where cnt>=2
   )
```